# Calling jpa repository.save() multiple times throws exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I want to call jpa repository.save multiple times.

But when I try to save the object for the second time, it throws the PersistentObjectException and says detached entity passed to persist.

The code and the exception are as follows. What am I missing?

```
public void createGame(GameTeamRequest gameTeamRequest) {
        for(Entry<String, Integer> hm : gameTeamRequest.getTeamsInnigsPostionMap().entrySet()) {
            GameTeam gameTeam = new GameTeam();
            Team team = new Team();
            team.setTeamName(hm.getKey());
            gameTeam.setTeam(team);
            gameTeam.setGame(gameTeamRequest.getGame());
            gameTeam.setInningsPosition(hm.getValue());
            gameTeamRepository.save(gameTeam);
        }
    }
```

The exception is as follows:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/iscorecard] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.dragonfly.iscorecard.domain.Game; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.dragonfly.iscorecard.domain.Game] with root cause
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.dragonfly.iscorecard.domain.Game
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:835)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:826)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:830)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:865)
```

Game class:

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "GAME")

public class Game extends Model {

@Column(name = "TOURNAMENT_ID")
private String tournamentId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "game")
private Set<GameTeam> gameTeam;          
}
```

Team Class:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "TEAM")

    public class Team extends Model {

    @Column(name = "TEAM_NAME")
    private String teamName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game")
    private Set<GameTeam> gameTeam;

}
```

GameTeam:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "GAME_TEAM")

    public class GameTeam extends Model {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "GAME_ID")
    private Game game;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private Team team;

    @Column(name = "INNINGS_POSITION")
    private int inningsPosition;

}
```

Comment: May be you are ignoring some JPA rules, your example has not all the information, I invite you to check this web site and read for something else http://aquiseprograma.co/category/jpa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is referring to the *Game* object, so it looks like you are setting a detachted *Game* to your second *GameTeam*.
You can fix this by adding (at least)

```
 cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }
```

to your mapping.

Comment: To which class and field should I add this?

Comment: To the mapping of the game Attribute in the GameTeam - Maybe add the code of your entites to your question for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Add your entities then